# C# Populate drop down based on data from cookie

Tags: c#, sql, webforms

I will see if I can explain this clearly enough.  I have 2 web forms.  One is a basic Forms Authentication login page and the other form displays tasks from multiple servers.  I am creating a cookie that stores the UserID.  Here is the code for my cookie:

```
        FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUser.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120), true, rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
```

On my other form, I have a drop down box that displays all servers by Server IP from the Servers table.

```
public void Populate()
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
            myConnection1.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerIP FROM Servers", myConnection1);
            SqlDataReader dropReader;
            dropReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            drpChoose.DataSource = dropReader;
            drpChoose.DataTextField = "ServerIP";
            drpChoose.DataValueField = "ServerIP";
            drpChoose.DataBind();
        }
```

I am calling Populate in Page Load.  I have another table that stores permissions.  It has UserID, ServerID, and Permission (read or execute).  Let's say that UserID 1 is associated with only ServerID 1 which has an IP of 192.168.0.10.  How can I get this one Server IP to display in the drop down?  I am pretty sure if I pass the cookie into the second form that I can take the UserID from that but I do not know where to begin.

I apologize if I have not given enough information.  I will provide more if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to do a join to your permissions table something like

```
SELECT ServerIP from Servers s, Permissions p where p.serverid = s.serverid and p.userid = :userIdFromCookie
```

Then you'll need to pass in the user id from your cookie into the Populate method and use a DbParameter to pass the value into your Sql command.

something like (this is pseudocode by the way as I'm not at my dev machine)

```
cmd.AddInParameter(":userIdFromCookie",dbType.AnsiString, Request.Cookies["mycookie"]["userid"])
```

Comment: I had done the join but did not know how to pass in the cookie.  Do I pass an HTTPCookie into Populate or do I pass the UserID?

Comment: I would retrieve the userid from your cookie in your page load and then pass the userid into Populate.

Comment: I added the code if (Request.Cookies["userID"] != null)
                {
                    int uid;
                    int.TryParse(Request.Cookies["userID"].ToString(), out uid);
                    Populate(uid); but uid continues to be 0 even though the cookie shows the right uid

Comment: Sorry.  I added the above to Page Load and then passed my variable to the Populate method.  My select statement is SELECT ServerIP FROM Servers s, Roles r where s.ServerID=r.ServerID AND r.UID=" + userid.  userid is the variable I passed in.

Comment: Got it.  int.TryParse(Request.Cookies["userID"].Value, out uid);  Needed to use .Value instead of .ToString().